# Error: Cannot find module '../config./db.config.js'

Tags: node.js, config

I am working a guide for an app using NodeJS, Express, MongoDB and React JS.
I have a problem with the command: node server.js, it returns this:
[image]

I did try most of the proposed solutions found online:

1. Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json && npm install
2. Installing config module (deleted here)
3. changed the location of the file and using different ways of writing the code: `./config/db.config.js`
   `./db.config.js`

Project structure:

[image: structure of the project]

db.config.js file content:

```
 module.exports = {
    url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/the_project"
  };
```

app/models/index.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const db = {};
db.mongoose = mongoose;
db.url = dbConfig.url;
db.projects = require("./project.model.js")(mongoose);

module.exports = db;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "the_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Tibou",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.3",
    "mongosh": "^0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Mongosh showing the database:

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not related to the database, it says the imported db.config.js file not locating path of the file, the config directory is 2 directories back from your index.js file so try 2 times ../../ like this, `require("../../config/db.config.js");`

Comment: This solved it! thank you! So every ".." equals a level in the project if I understood.

Comment: Yes, and _that_ has nothing to do with Node.js itself, but just filesystem directories.